# VsVim & ReSharper, up and down inside Go To Everything/Type popup

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, vsvim

I am looking for approach to avoid pressing arrow keys on keyboard when using ReSharper's "Go to Everything / Type" popup.

I was able to bind Alt+J and Alt+K to Up and Down in ReSharper's InteliSense popup, but can't figure out what can be done for navigation.

Thanks.

Comment: I just discovered a guide recently that mentions using AutoHotKey to do some stuff like this. Perhaps it'll be useful to you: https://github.com/keithn/vsvimguide